# Storing data in hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I want to store in hyperledger data about exchange usd to eur, something like(date -> rate):

```
"21 Mar 2017" -> 0.92940
"22 Mar 2017" -> 0.92583
"23 Mar 2017" -> 0.92699
```

so, as I understand, first I should call **deploy** a chaincode with empty map,
and everyday I should call **invoke** to update the map

is this how it should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically yes.

You can write your chaincode, deploy it then you will be able to call the **invoke** method to store your data in the world state.

There is no need to initialize a map or whatsoever on the **deploy**. The data on the blockchain is modeled so it can store **key/value**.

Answer (score 0):

You can write chaincode to store that data in the world-state. You can dynamically run invokes by wrapping cron type logic within a nodeSDK javascript function to run the invokes based on time or other business rules.